# Use regex to parse HTML in json response

Tags: python, html, json

I have this json response (returned via python) with nested HTML in `label`:

```
{
"point": {
"lat": "27.938829",
"long": "-82.322109"
},
"label": "<div class=\"lifestyle-results_item lifestyle-results_item-b\"><div class=\"locationinfo_area\"><h4 style=\"width:230px;\">At Petco</h4><h3 class=\"dealer_cat\"></h3><address style=\"left:240px\">2434 West Brandon Boulevard<br />Brandon, FL 33511<br /><br />813-571-0120<div class=\"contentinfo_area_operated\"></div></address></div><div class=\"contentinfo_area\"><div class=\"contentinfo_area_zip\">4.2 mi from Zip Code 33584</div></div><a href=\"https://vetcoclinics.petco.com?store_number=PET2722&source=vetcoclinics\" target=\"_blank\"><div class=\"contentinfo_area\"><div class=\"contentinfo_area_reserve\">BOOK NOW</div></div></a><div class=\"timeinfo_area\"><b>Sun, May 9</b><br/> at 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM<br /><b>Sun, May 16</b><br/> at 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM<br /><b>Sun, May 23</b><br/> at 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM<br /><b>Sun, May 30</b><br/> at 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM<br /><b>Sun, June 6</b><br/> at 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM<br /></div></div>",
"title": "At Petco ",
"html": "<div class=\"googlemap_bubble\"><b>At Petco<br><span></span></b><br />2434 West Brandon Boulevard<br />Brandon, FL 33511<br />813-571-0120<br /></div>"
}
```

How can I use regex to extract the blow from `label`:

- 2434 West Brandon Boulevard
- Brandon, FL 33511
- 813-571-0120
- [https://vetcoclinics.petco.com?store_number=PET2722&source=vetcoclinics\](https://vetcoclinics.petco.com?store_number=PET2722&source=vetcoclinics%5C)
- PET2722

Comment: you can just make a new element, make that its innerHTML, then read from there ;-;

Comment: What environment/language do you use to parse this JSON?

Comment: @geauser python.

Comment: @TheBombSquad Interesting, okay I will attempt.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html @a1234 I won't be able to help you much more as it's been awhile since I've used Python, but it will certainly simply your code compared with the Regex solution.

Comment: @geauser Ahh yes, that is a good idea. Thank you, I will keep at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid using regex and sticking with HTML parsing using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Assuming you have your JSON data in a variable called `data` you can do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlData = data["label"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData, 'html.parser')

address = soup.address.string
link = soup.a.get('href')
```

Then you can use a simple split to get the additional data in the `address` variable:

```
addressParts = address.split("<br />")
```

And use an url parser to get the `store_number` parameter from your `link` variable:

```
from urllib import parse

storeName = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(link).query)['store_name'][0]
```

You will end up with

- The `addressParts` list containing the elements `["2434 West Brandon Boulevard", "Brandon, FL 33511", "", "813-571-0120"]`
- The `link` variable containing
  `https://vetcoclinics.petco.com?store_number=PET2722&source=vetcoclinics\`
- The `storeName` variable containing `PET2722`